# How to have a background image in Altair Python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, altair

I'm trying to use Altair to have a dynamic map, I can easily do the dynamic part, however I am trying to add an image as background of the plot (bitmap image), I cannot find any functions in this purpose and every example on the Altair documentation is based on Url/Json feature. Does anyone have already done this kind of plot ? Is it possible to maybe combine a matplotlib with the background image and a dynamic part such as in Altair ?

Thanks Everyone,
Antoine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to embed a bitmap image within Altair. Vega supports an [image mark](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/marks/image/), but that has not yet made its way into Vega-Lite, which drives the API of Altair.

Requests for this feature in Vega-Lite can be tracked in [this GitHub Issue](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/3758).

Comment: It seems this has been included in Vega-Lite now: https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/image.html